# ClipperLib - Union of few meshes(clip or subject?)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mesh, clipperlib

I am using ClipperLib (C# version).

What I want to achieve is that for given coordinates of few meshes, I have union of them as an answer. For two intersecting meshes and a third one (totally separate), I predict getting two element answer:

1. Union of intersecting meshes
2. Coordinates of the third mesh (that separate one).

However, what I am actually getting is some weird answer with missing coordinates of intersecting meshes.

What I do:

I add coordinates of those 3 meshes to the Clip, and then execute this. I am wondering if this is connected to the empty subject path. If anyone encountered a problem like this, I would appreciate any help here.

Comment: If you can share code, it will make it easier to help out.

Comment: Actually I solved this, by changing the PolyFillType to Non-Zero(I used to set it Even-Odd)

Comment: @Power Could you share code of this. I'm trying to do similar thing in ClipperLib and have problems with that.